# Qt/QML: Text with inline QML elements

Tags: c++, qt, text, qml, qt-quick

We are building a graphical user interface with QtQuick/QML. We have some dynamic, multi-line text coming from a database, which should be displayed in the application. Currently, we are using the `Text` element to display the text. However, we need some QML components inline embedded into the text. For this, the text coming from the database contains placeholders such as `::checkbox|1::` which should then be replaced and displayed by the program.

In HTML, this is easy, you can simply mix inline elements with text to produce a result like this:

[image]

but in QML, this seems to be more difficult, as `Text` elements cannot be word-wrapped into two halves if there is not enough space (both the text and the container size should be dynamic).

The best solution we could come up with, is creating a `Flow` layout with one `Text` element for each word, but this seems too hacky.
Using `RichText` with HTML is not enogh, since we really need our custom QML elements in the text.
Also, we want to avoid using a `WebView` due to performance reasons.

Is there a sophisticated way to implement this with QML/C++ only?

Comment: I guess the easiest way is to split the string by spaces and so wrap all token to `Text` or `Button` or whatever ant put that into `Flow`. Yes, in this case you lose all text alignments, space rules etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can create custom widgets and embed them into QML: 
[Writing QML Extensions with C++](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-tutorials-extending-qml-example.html)

Comment: OK, I guess I need to write a little text parser which can break lines and apply the styles from the previous line to the wrapped portion

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried placing something in the middle, but I did try adding a tag to the beginning (and I might try adding a tag at the end).

QML's Text has a `lineLaidOut` signal that let's you indent the first line of text.

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-text.html#lineLaidOut-signal

Here's what I did:

[image]

```
Text {      
    text: issue.summary

    onLineLaidOut: {
        if (line.number == 0) {
            var indent = tagRect.width + tagRect.rightMargin
            line.x += indent
            line.width -= indent
        }
    }

    Rectangle {
        id: tagRect
        implicitWidth: padding + tagText.implicitWidth + padding
        implicitHeight: padding + tagText.implicitHeight + padding
        color: "#400"
        property int padding: 2
        property int rightMargin: 8
        radius: 3

        Text {
            id: tagText
            anchors.centerIn: parent
            text: issue.product
            color: "#fff"
        }
    }
}
```